# Struct.unpack binary file as uint16 issue, python reading less numbers than expected

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, data-structures, binary

Ok, so I have binary file which I am reading with python and I'm checking results with matlab.

```
#Constants
RecordsPerBuffer = 10
RecordLength = 9920
Records = 1000
Channels = 2

SamplesPerAline = Channels*RecordLength*RecordsPerBuffer
AlinesPerBscan = Records/RecordsPerBuffer
onearm='RawSpectraBgn.dat'
with open(onearm, "rb") as f:
    fileContent = f.read()
    print(type(fileContent)), "FileContentType"
    print(len(fileContent)), "FileContentLenght", len(fileContent)*1./10
    for j in range (0, AlinesPerBscan):
        for i in range (0, SamplesPerAline):
                back[i,j]=struct.unpack_from('!H',fileContent[(j*SamplesPerAline+i*2):(j*SamplesPerAline+i*2+2)])[0]
        #print back.shape
```

So I have an array with AlinesPerBscan rows and AlinesPerBscan columns, and I plot rows in python and in matlab. While in matlab each row looks the same, in python plot looks exactly the same as in matlab except for the fact that each row begins around 2hundred points earlier and ends earlier so there is the beginning of a new row at the end of each row. Suprisingly, data doesn't end even though binary data lenght is in accordance with number of elements in the arrays. I spent already few days trying to gfigure that out, please help!

Comment: Why are you using `struct` instead of `numpy.fromfile`?  What you are doing is one line of code using `numpy.fromfile`.

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `j` by the number of records, not the total size if those records. Assuming performance isn't an issue, it's much clearer to read the two bytes on demand rather than trying to simulate the file pointer yourself.

```
with open(onearm, "rb") as f:
    fileContent = f.read()
    print(type(fileContent)), "FileContentType"
    print(len(fileContent)), "FileContentLenght", len(fileContent)*1./10
    for j in range (0, AlinesPerBscan):
        for i in range (0, SamplesPerAline):
            back[i,j] = struct.unpack("!H", f.read(2))[0]
```

Although `f.read(2)` only returns two bytes, there are numerous buffers involved that prevent you from actually accessing the file system once per call.